# found this problem on my android : AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, android-fragments

ive tried to make bottom navigation but from tutorial, but im  getting this error massage

```
D:\praktikum\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_home.xml:8: AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token).
```

heres my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="www.dedykuncoro.com"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#448AFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="ID"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Username"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#00555555"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ive read similar question on stackoverflow their problem is /> but I hve checked it on my code everything is good, but I don't know why I get this error

thank you so much for your time and answer

Comment: That's because you didn't close the root tag with an angle bracket (`>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't closed the opening tag of your RelativeLayout

Existing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
```

Should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">
```